# Google Query - Date range filter that works with both: dates and no dates

Tags: sql, google-sheets

I have this query which works:

```
=query('Database'!A1:AD979,"select* where (J > date '"&TEXT(A2,"yyyy-MM-dd")&"' and J < date '"&TEXT(B2,"yyyy-MM-dd")&"') and AD = 'Active'")
```

I have this filter:

- Start date = A2
- End Date = B2

When I do need to use a date range, the query works perfectly. However, when I leave the filter with no dates aiming to see all the value from the database that match 'Active', no data show up.

How can I leave empty filter dates, but still see the value that matches my 3rd argument, in this case 'Active'

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using this query so that if you remove either date it will act as a wild card

```
=query(Database!A1:AD979,"select* where (J > date '"&TEXT(A2,"yyyy-MM-dd")&"' or '"&A2&"' = '') and (J < date '"&TEXT(B2,"yyyy-MM-dd")&"' or '"&B2&"' = '') and AD = 'Active'")
```

Answer (score 0):

I can get query to work with a blank from date but not a blank to date. However, I got it to work fine with filter, Try this:

```
=filter(Database!$A1:$AD, Database!J1:J>A2,IF(B2<>"",Database!J:J<B2,Database!J1:J<max(Database!J1:J)),Database!AD1:AD="Active")
```